# TFS 2012 - Compare With Previous.. Previous

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I tried diging to find who wrote a certain line in a project.
I've Annotate the cs file notice there was a change couple of days ago..
When clicking "Compare With Previous" I notice that the last developer only added indent spaces.
I want to see the previous of that version.

My workaround is to use View History and start comparing.. But that's not fun.

Any clue how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing a Get Specific version to download a previous version to your local workspace, then doing an Annotate.  I think that should work.